# Magento 2 extention creator

Tags: magento2, extensions, tools

Is there way to create an Magento 2 extension template code as a start?

In this way, we need not learn all the naming convention, but still get it working.

More like an hello world application with various different methods like front-end page, back-end page, crons etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few online tools mentioned below which you can use to create basic extensions/modules with  front-end page, back-end page, cron jobs etc.

- https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2-module-creator.php
- https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/
- https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: Thank you.  Of the 3, I liked the second.  The first and last have more options though.  This is quite helpful.